# VMWare Player 5.0 Upgrade - Bridged Networking No Longer Works

Tags: upgrade, network-adapter, vmware-player

I've been using VMWare Player 4 on my Windows 7 PC, running my VMs under a bridged networking configuration without any problem.  I settled on bridged networking two reasons...

1. I often use VMs to host web applications for test purposes.
2. I never could get NAT to work for me anyway, but no love lost, considering reason #1.

Now that I've upgraded to VMWare Player 5, the situation has completely reversed.  In other words, bridged networking no longer works at all, and NAT *does*.

Has anyone else come across this?  Any ideas on getting bridged networking to work again?

This happens with both Windows and Linux guest OSes.  VMWare Tools has been fully updated.  I've tried the usual vmnetcfg.exe utility fix, to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

i could never find vmware-tools under vmware player 5, so, as i got my old installer from version 4, extracted the entire vmware-tools from .cab (network.cab i guess) to any folder on my pc, and voilá, run vmnetcfg.exe from there.

Answer (score 0):

I got the `vmnetcfg` file for version 5.0.1 from [this tar file](http://softwareupdate.vmware.com/cds/vmw-desktop/ws/9.0.1/894247/windows/core/VMware-workstation-9.0.1-894247.exe.tar). Untar it, extract it, and look for `core.cab`. That file contains `vmnetcfg`.